# System Image and Backup& Restore

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, operating-systems

I know there is threads talking about these 2 concepts, but I still have a few questions. So I have 3 physical drives (Drive C,D,E). My C drive contains my OS (Windows 10 already activated, so will be activated when doing the system image) and my personal files. Drive D is where all my steam games are downloaded. Drive E is extra backup for anything I might need. Drive E is empty as of this moment. Anyways, I have been running into issues and I am afraid my drive or something my fail soon, so I want to back things up essentially. So my questions are:

1. Does System Image restore the windows 10 Product Key/Activation as well?
2. I keep getting conflicting information when looking this question up, but does System Image restore my personal files like an excel worksheet for example or is that where I want to use Backup & Restore?
3. If I want to also copy my D drive in the System Image, how exactly would this work when the drive does fail and I am going to use the system image? Since it is all on one file. I would need to put the contents from Drive D back into another drive separate from my contents on drive C. So how do I do what I want essentially?
4. For number 3 being successful, does it keep my icon's on my C drive with the actual files on the D drive? Does it look the same essentially as when I created it?

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does System Image restore the Windows 10 Product Key/Activation as well?

Windows 10 uses a digital entitlement.  Your product key is stored in ACPI table, and is automatically detected by Windows 10, so knowing your product is key isn't necessary with Windows 10.  The use of Backup and Restore (Windows 7) does not affect the activation status of Windows.The activation status of Windows.  **If Windows 10 is not activated for any reason, when you attempt to activate Windows, the product key will automatically be detected.**

> I keep getting conflicting information when looking this question up, but does System Image restore my personal files like an excel worksheet for example or is that where I want to use Backup & Restore?

Backup and Restore (Windows 7), System Images, do indeed include your personal files.  However, you will back up the entire drive, you don't have any control over any exclusions.

> So how do I do what I want essentially?

You cannot create a system image, if the system image, includes a location included in the system image.  You will want to back up the disk that contains the system image using another method.  You will not have control over what is restored using Backup and Restore (Windows 7).

Additionally, the system image can contain any partitions you want except, the one where the system image is going to be located.

Any partitions that are selected, 
will not show, up in the list of disk to store the backup.  **You can backup disks other than the system disk.**

> When a restoration is performed, does it keep my icon's on my C drive, with the actual files on the D drive?  Does it look the same essentially as when I created it?

The system state will be exactly as it was.

Comment: Depending on the size of your HDDs, creating a system image will take a very long time, in my experience a single 1 TB drive could take more than a day.

Comment: @BobG.- Respectfully, I feel I have answered all of your questions, as they were asked within the question body.  I still feel I have addressed your concern with regards to the activation status of the system after a restoration is performed.  However, I have made yet another update to my answer, and slightly reworded one of my statements.

Comment: Yes, fixer is right essentially. I will try another source is clarify, you got about half of my questions answered, so thanks for that and thanks for trying.

Comment: Exactly, I am very new to this concept as I just found out about it.